# Grep: max words before and after match

Tags: grep

Is it possibile to make grep show a maximum number of *words* before and after the match?
For example, given the row

```
aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff ggg hhh iii jjj kkk lll mmm nnn ooo ppp qqq rrr sss
```

I'd like grep not to return whole line, but only, say, 3 words before and after the match. for example, searching for 'iii', the result would be

```
fff ggg hhh iii jjj kkk lll
```

I've tried this but no result is returned:

```
grep -o '\w{0, 20}MY_SEARCH\w{0, 20}' *
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on your question as to what you are intending to do?

Comment: I don't think `grep` can do that. You may have to write up a small script like this `awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i=="iii") {for(k=i-3;k<=i+3;k++) printf("%s ",$k)} print ""}' filename`

Comment: I have modified the post with new script..Check that out

Comment: You can modify your command to: `grep -oP '(\w+ ){0,3}bbb( \w+){0,3}'`.

Answer (score 2):

```
string='aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff ggg hhh iii jjj kkk lll mmm nnn ooo ppp qqq rrr sss'

echo $string | grep -oP '(([a-zA-Z]+) ){0,3}iii( ([a-zA-Z]+)){0,3}'
```

If I've understood your question right, this should do it when the maximum number of words on either side are 3.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to convert the spaces to newlines and then use -A and -B option and then reconvert \n to space.

```
$ echo "aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff ggg hhh iii jjj kkk lll mmm nnn ooo ppp qqq rrr sss" | tr ' ' '\n' | grep -A3 -B3 "iii" | tr '\n' ' '
```

op=>    fff ggg hhh iii jjj kkk lll

I know its a crude approach but need to check any other better option is present.

I wrote a small shell script with this logic to handle multiple files. Check this

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in `find . -name "*.txt"`
do
    FNAME=$i
    MATCHED=""
    if grep "iii" $i > /dev/null 2>&1
    then
        MATCHED=`cat $i | tr ' ' '\n' | grep -A3 -B3 "iii" | tr '\n' ' '`
    fi

    if [ "$MATCHED" != "" ]
    then
        echo "$FNAME|$MATCHED"
    fi
done
```

Comment: thanks, this may work, but will it work when the output is not a single line but '*' and hence apply it to multiple files?

Comment: since i play around with \n , i need to try this

Comment: @pistacchio The `awk` one-liner posted in the comments can scan through multiple files. Though depending on the file size it may not be that efficient.

Comment: @Raghuram This will cause issues with filenames having spaces. You can do `for i in /path/to/dir/*.txt` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -E -o '.{0, 3}iii.{0, 3}'
```

it will output this

```
hhh iii jjj
```

if you want to remove 'iii', you can also pipe a sed

```
grep -E -o '.{0,3}iii.{0,3}' | sed 's/iii//g'
```

it will output this

```
hhh jjj
```